# Authorization MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authorization

I have a controller with an `Authorize` attribute on it that accepts users for the Worker role:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Worker")]
public class AuthorizedController : Controller
```

The rest of the controllers inherit from this controller.

In one of my controllers I want to give access to authorized users that is not in any role for some actions. Is there a way to inherit from `AuthorizedController` and yet give access to some of the inherited controller actions for users that are not in the worker role?

Comment: Have you considered using XACML in your MVC app?

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the [Authorize] on the controller and the [Authorize(Roles = "Worker")] on the Action, so you can control better the authorization.